# Best implementation of a large number of bit flags in php and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone offer a solution for implementing flags in php and mysql.  I have a large number of flags that represent owning items.  There over 200 different item, but over time this will grow to as many as 500-600.

My initial thought was to store this information in a data blob, and update it in a trigger in mysql.  But it appears that bit operations are limited to 64 bits.

The basic operation is to give an item by id type (say item 156) which would set 156th bit in the blob.

Comment: I'd put the items into a table and then use a foreign key to link them to the owners.

Comment: whats wrong with *user_id | item_id* ??

Comment: Those both are possible solutions.  Im concerned with the data size of the tables and the speed of access with millions of users and 500+ items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several answers here that should be considered prior to using this solution.  In my particular case I analyzed the use case and it was necessary to use binary data and bit twiddle the results.  So to the solution....

First the mysql data type was varbinary({maxLen}).  where maxlen is the size of bits I would probably need.  In my case I chose 64 which provides me with 512 bits.  I chose this because it doesn't pad out the data.  This was because it wanted to store the smallest amount of data and it wasn't until later that users would begin needing larger bits flipped.

Second the php... (WHAT CRAP, but it works) - I select from the DB, convert, bittwiddle and update.  But there is a bit more to it than that.

```
$q = $sqli->query("Select binaryFlags from Table where id= $id");
$r = $q->fetch_assoc();
$c = $r['binaryFlags']; // holds the binary raw data
$c = bin2hex($c);// convert to hex - don't know why I can't convert directly to dec
$c = hexdec($c);// now i have a hex string convert to dec
$c |= 1 << ($flag-1); // now i have dec i can OR $flag is the bit to flip and is 1 based)
$c = '0x'.dechex($c); //convert back to hex and add the '0x' so that the sql will know how to deal with it.
$q = $sqli->query("update Table set binaryFlags = $c"); // acutall update with proper binary.
```

Hope this can help someone else AND if anyone has a better way, or reasons why I had to jump thru hoops please leave a comment

Comment: Once, when your PO says _"I want to find all users that have item 156"_ you'll find yourself in a deep ass.

Comment: thanks for the input, I will put that in the design doc to cover my own rear :D

Answer (score 2):

If you store 200 "items" as bit flags, that will occupy 25 bytes per user.  Regardless of the number of users.

If instead you have a `UserItems` table with two columns, , , that is 8 bytes per pair.  If users have, on average, 3 items or fewer, then the normalized approach is actually smaller than the bit-packing approach.

It also offers several advantages.  The normalized approach would naturally have an `items` table with descriptive information about the items.  This could be easily joined in, so you would know which items are red, or in German, or size 16, or take diesel fuel -- whatever the appropriate attributes are for your items.  And these could have item hierarchies with important category information as well.

In addition, the basic `UserItems` table might be too small.  Perhaps you want other information about the acquisition of an item -- such as when it was acquired, or the quantity.  Well, you can add columns to the `UserItem` table.  The bit-packing approach is a bit less flexible.

The advice is to use a standard database approach.  This has worked on many different applications, some bigger than the one you are contemplating.  If you really do understand the problem and understand the performance implications of different approaches, there are some circumstances where bit-packing could be the right solution.  But it is not the way to start the design.

Comment: An interesting observation.  If you distill your answer down farther I could probably pack the columns down to 2 bytes per totaling 4 bytes per pair.  That means my break even is 6 items.  In this particular case I expect even the first time users to have at least 4 items with any casual user having probably 10+ and heavy users having easily 50+.  Your analysis is solid and I agree that that majority of the time I would use a database approach.  But in this particular instance, I believe that the bitpacking probably the best solution if data size is the most important issue.

Comment: I don't know if it is.  At bests if I use bit packing I believe I am going to have to always query the blob bit twiddle the data and then update the row.  I will have to take some more time and analyze the problem and the rate at which this will occur.

Comment: actually 6 bytes is the best, forgot, userid has to be an int... means that break even is 4.  That increases as the number of items begins to increase... At 500 items, the break even becomes 10-11...

Answer (score 0):

As I see it:

- you have a list of objects and a list of potential owners
- you want to implement a "owner owns object" relation

The simplest solution would be to have a table that associates an owner and an object.

A record in this table would be equivalent to a cell in the matrix representing the ownership relation.

If this matrix is populated sparsely enough, then the table is a good enough solution.

If you know that an average owner will own 50 objects or so, then you might want to organize your objects in groups and have a slightly more complex relation: "owner owns objects in object group", where you store the owner id, the group id and a bitmap specifying which objects are owned within the group.

Provided your owners don't pick items at random (i.e. you can guess reasonably well which objects will be likely to be owned together), this approach would be more flexible than a huge bitmap for each owner, that you would have to update each time you add a new set of objects to your database, and probably more size-efficient.